# Wordpress SSO without using 3rd party plugins on Azure, is it possible?

Tags: azure, wordpress, single-sign-on, adfs

I'm setting up a Wordpress installation on Azure which is using an external ADFS provider for single sign-on. Up to now, the Wordpress installation was self-hosted and used the miniOrange wordpress SSO plugin to provide single sign-on. If possible, it would be nice to not rely on the 3rd party plugin anymore.

When Wordpress is hosted on Azure, is it possible to handle the external SSO directly with Azure? Or is a 3rd party SSO plugin still required in wordpress?

Comment: I don't think Wordpress does SSO natively, you'll probably need to use a plugin.